# Apache on MAMP periodically stops working

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, mamp

Apache periodically stops working on MAMP (with OS X 10.6.8). It'll be running fine but then it will suddenly stop serving pages. The status light stays green and the error logs are clean. Rebooting my computer sometimes fixes the problem, but not always. I've also noticed that the same problem can occur when I'm connected to certain WiFi networks.

This is incredibly frustrating (and the MAMP form moderators haven't approved my question, which I submitted over a week ago). Can anybody help me troubleshoot?

EDIT: Weirdly, 127.0.0.1:8888 works but not localhost:8888. Any idea why?

Comment: Is it serving over IPv4 only?  If so, localhost:8888 might be defaulting to IPv6 and failing for that reason.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that. Can you tell me how?

Comment: Run the command `netstat -an | grep "8888.*LISTEN"` and see if it lists "tcp4", "tcp6", or both (either as two entries or "tcp46").